# Cannot set state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add class on Mouse Enter and remove class from on Mouse Out. For that I am using state I have declare state in component class but I cannot set in the component

My code

```
class MegaMenu extends React.Component {
  public state = { addClass: false }
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.MegaMenu}>
        <div className={styles["menu-container"]}>
          <div className={styles.menu}>
            <MenuList Options={menus} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MenuList = (props: IMenuListProps) => {
  const { width, height } = WidthAndHeight();
  const handleOnMouseEnter = () => {
    if (width > 943) {
      console.log('Mouse Enter')
    }
  }
  const handleOnMouseOut = () => {
    if (width > 943) {
      console.log('Mouse Out')
    }
  }

  return (
    <ul onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter}>
      {
        props.Options.map((Option: IMenu, index: number) => (
          <li key={index} className={(Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) ? styles["menu-dropdown-icon"] : styles["normal-sub"]} onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter} onMouseOut={handleOnMouseOut}>
            <a href={Option.link}>{Option.name}</a>
            {/* Base Case */}
            {
              (Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) &&
              <MenuList Options={Option.subitem} />
            }
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}



export default MegaMenu
```

What I am doing wrong !!

Answer (score 0):

1. define state in MenuList component;
2. use setState() to set the value in handlers;
3. Use the value in the render method to set a class.

There is your code modified (I'm not sure where you want to add/remove a class):

```
class MegaMenu extends React.Component {
  public state = { addClass: false }
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.MegaMenu}>
        <div className={styles["menu-container"]}>
          <div className={styles.menu}>
            <MenuList Options={menus} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MenuList = (props: IMenuListProps) => {
  private state = { className: '' };

  const { width, height } = WidthAndHeight();
  const handleOnMouseEnter = () => {
    if (width > 943) {
      setState({ className: 'some-class' });
    }
  }
  const handleOnMouseOut = () => {
    if (width > 943) {
      setState({ className: '' });
    }
  }

  return (
    <ul onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter}> className={{this.state.className}}
      {
        props.Options.map((Option: IMenu, index: number) => (
          <li key={index} className={(Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) ? styles["menu-dropdown-icon"] : styles["normal-sub"]} onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter} onMouseOut={handleOnMouseOut}>
            <a href={Option.link}>{Option.name}</a>
            {/* Base Case */}
            {
              (Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) &&
              <MenuList Options={Option.subitem} />
            }
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}



export default MegaMenu
```

Comment: I am really new to it. Kindly can you help me as per my question

Comment: No it gives error on this line <MenuList Options={menus} /> this does not works

Comment: Sorry, it should be `this.state.className`. I fixed the code.

Comment: I could not find where you change

Comment: Access the `state` in a template through `this` so `className={{this.state.className}}`.